# Finding smallest neighbour in a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have some code that is supposed to find the smallest of the 8 neighboring cells in a 2D array. When this code runs, the smallest is then moved to, and the code run again in a loop. However when it is run the code ends up giving a stack overflow error as it keeps jumping between two points. This seems to be a logical paradox as if Y < X then X !< Y. So it think it is my code at fault, rather than my logic. Here's my code:

```
private Point findLowestWeight(Point current) {
    float lowest = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    Point ret = new Point(-1, -1);
    LinkedList<Point> pointList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            if (!(i == 0 && j == 0)) {
                if ((current.x + i >= 0 && current.x + i <= imageX - 2) 
                 && (current.y + j >= 0 && current.y + j <= imageY - 2)) {
                    pointList.add(new Point(current.x + i, current.y + j));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (Point p : pointList){
        if (map[p.x][p.y] < lowest){
            lowest = map[p.x][p.y];
            ret = p;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are imageX and imageY for?

Comment: If you are searching through the neighbors and excluding the center, then there is always going to be an exchange. You should compare `lowest` with `map[current.x][current.y]` to see if exchange of the points is actually necessary.

Comment: imageX and imageY are the width and height of the array, due to the way the data is structured there will always be a lower value for every point except one special case, which is this code is never run on

Comment: btw. stack overflow error suggests some recursive code. it's not in this example, so maybe it's in something that's calling this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a stopping case.

> find the smallest of the 8 neighboring cells in a 2D array. When this code runs, the smallest is then moved to, and the code run again in a loop

is a fine way to start but says nothing about stopping.

Do you care about the value of the current cell?  If so you need to check 9 not 8.  If you simply want to move down hill then you need to check where you've been or any flat multi-cell valley will put you into an infinite loop.  Consider only moving if moving down.

If you truly don't care where you are then even a single cell valley will put you into an infinite loop as you bounce in and out of it.  In which case you'd need some other stopping condition.  Consider stopping after `imageX * imageY` iterations.

Comment: Ah, thank you, this code was called from a recursive function and there was a typo in the stopping clause

Answer (score 0):

Do you move even if the smallest neighbour is greater than the value in the center?
Example:

```
2 2 2 2
2 0 1 2
2 2 2 2
```

You start with center cell 0. The smallest neighbour is 1. If you move to 1, the smallest neighbour is 0. You can continue endless.
Probably you should not move, if the smallest neighbour is greater than the current cell.